# How to avoid overlapping of title of marker in unfolding maps?

Tags: java, maps, processing

I am using unfolding maps to create markers.When a user hovers over a marker the title is displayed.But the other markers overlap the title so it hides the information presented in title. To prevent from this, i used PGraphics to draw the title as:

```
    public void showTitle(PGraphics pg, float x, float y)
{
    String name = getCity() + " " + getCountry() + " ";
    String pop = "Pop: " + getPopulation() + " Million";
    /
    /buffer is defined already.
    buffer.beginDraw();
    buffer.fill(255, 255, 255);
    buffer.textSize(12);
    buffer.rectMode(PConstants.CORNER);
    buffer.rect(x, y-TRI_SIZE-39, Math.max(pg.textWidth(name), pg.textWidth(pop)) + 6, 39);
    buffer.fill(0, 0, 0);
    buffer.textAlign(PConstants.LEFT, PConstants.TOP);
    buffer.text(name, x+3, y-TRI_SIZE-33);
    buffer.text(pop, x+3, y - TRI_SIZE -18);
    buffer.endDraw();


}
```

And then drawing buffer on screen through method

```
public void draw() {
      map.draw();
      image(buffer, 0,0);
      }
```

It resolves the problem, now the title is not overlapped with markers but its not drawn right below the marker instead its drawn some where random on screen as shown in image
[image] How can i avoid it? Any help please.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You can use simplified hard-coded examples instead of your entire sketch.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the position of the buffer before you draw it. Basically, you need to change this line:

```
image(buffer, 0,0);
```

To something like this:

```
image(buffer, bufferX, bufferY);
```

You'll have to calculate `bufferX` and `bufferY` depending on where you want the buffer to show up. A very dumb implementation might be something like this:

```
public void showTitle(PGraphics pg, float x, float y)
{
   bufferX = x;
   bufferY = y;
   //rest of your code
```

I'm not familiar enough with Unfolding Maps to tell you exactly what to do, but those are the basics. Note that Unfolding Maps might be doing its own translations, so you might have to use the `pushMatrix()` and `popMatrix()` functions. Also note that you might need to project from map space to screen space. The Unfolding Maps library probably has documentation on how to do that.

Comment: I did almost the same as you have mentioned. I stored the screen positions of selected marker and used those in image() function but it did not work that way. Isnt there any other solution that provides "focus" on current component?

Comment: @BatulMajid I don't really know what you mean by providing focus. If you have follow-up questions please post an updated [mcve] in a new question, and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 1):

In setup you created a map with some size and offset. Buffer should be created with same size.

But most important is to draw buffer with same offset.

Your title is just drawn with negative offset, not random.

```
private PGraphics buffer;

public void setup() {
    size(900, 700);
    //Create map with offset
    map = new UnfoldingMap(this, 200, 50, 650 ,600, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
    //Create buffer, same size as map
    buffer = createGraphics(650, 600);
    //rest of the code..
}

public void draw() {
    background(0);
    map.draw();
    //put buffer over the map, with same offset
    image(buffer, 200, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the same Coursera course (Object Oriented Programming in Java) and worked on fixing this feature as well. Here is how I fixed this problem.

I realized that the titles are covered because the markers are drawn over and over inside the map.draw() method in draw() section of the EarthquakeCityMap class. So the fix would be moving the showTitle implementation from marker classes to the EarthquakeCityMap class, and let the title be drawn at the screen position of the markers instead of latitude and longitude.

The SimplePointMarker class in UnfoldingMaps Library has a method getScreenPosition() inherited from AbstractMarker class. See the JavaDoc for more details. Because the CommonMarker class is a subclass of SimplePointMarker class, and EarthquakeMarker class is a subclass of the CommonMarker, EarthquakeMarker class has the getScreenPosition() method available as default as well.

Below is how the method of showing earthquake titles look like in the EarthquakeCityMap.java file. Please note that you can use Processing's graphics methods here automatically because the EarthquakeCityMap class extends PApplet.

```
    /** Show the title of the earthquake if this marker is selected */
    private void showEqTitle(EarthquakeMarker m, UnfoldingMap map)
    {   
        float x = m.getScreenPosition(map).x;
        float y = m.getScreenPosition(map).y;

        String title = m.getTitle();

        pushStyle();
        
        rectMode(PConstants.CORNER);
        stroke(110);
        fill(255,255,255);
        rect(x, y + 15, textWidth(title) + 6, 18, 5);
        textAlign(PConstants.LEFT, PConstants.TOP);
        fill(0);
        text(title, x + 3 , y +18);

        popStyle();
    }
```

And here is how I implement the method above in the draw() function.

```
    public void draw() {
        background(0);
        map.draw();
        addKey();
        
        for (Marker m: quakeMarkers) {
            EarthquakeMarker eq = (EarthquakeMarker) m;
            if (m.isSelected()) {
                showEqTitle(eq, map);
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally, here's the resulting image showing the titles are no longer covered by the markers. Horray~
[The earthquake map display when the mouse hovers one of the earthquake marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue1J7.png)